# Setting global instance variable based on domain in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, instance-variables, multisite

I have a single Rails application that is currently being accessed via lets say *https://www.domain1.com* and I would like to enable the application to be accessed by a second domain, lets say *https://www.domain2.com* which would then set a global instance variable.

I would then like to use this instance variable to control certain things on the page such as content, styles and images.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

E.g.

```
def my_action
  @domain_instance_variable = request.domain
  $domain_global_variable = request.domain
end
```

A global variable and an instance variable are different things. An instance variable is scoped to an instance of a class, and a global variable has a global scope. It's a good rule of thumb to minimize scope.

In the case of Rails code in controllers, views or helpers, you can just call `request.domain` directly instead of assigning that to a variable.

Comment: Thanks, this worked nicely. I ended up adding a before_action into my application controller that would set the instance variable and then I pick that up in my views.